# Make multiple boot2docker virtual machines

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, virtualbox, boot2docker

I'm using boot2docker as the image for my virtual machine (I'm running Windows 7, 64 bit), but I would like to be able to create another vm with the same image.

If I try `New` in the VirtualBox application, I have the usual choice of Ubuntu, Windows etc. but not the boot2docker image. Alternatively, if I just use the Boot2Docker shortcut/shell script, it automatically connects to the already existing vm and doesn't give me a choice to make a new one.

So my question is, how do I make another VM using the boot2docker image?

Answer (score 0):

You can try (not tested) the changes described in "[Multiple Boot2docker Profiles On Mac OS X](http://blog.turret.io/multiple-boot2docker-profiles-on-mac-os-x/)" (which *might* be adaptable to Windows, provided you have a `HOME` environment variable set to any folder considered as "HOME". Usually it is `%USERPROFILE%`)

```
boot2docker down
copy %HOME%\.boot2docker\profile %HOME%\.boot2docker\new_profile
# edit `%HOME%\.boot2docker\new_profile` with a new VM name: 
# VM = "boot2docker-vm-2"
set BOOT2DOCKER_PROFILE=%HOME%/.boot2docker/new_profile
boot2docker init
```